# Where to find com.ibm.json.nosql.DB class for DB2?

Tags: db2

I'm using DB2 Express-C for windows and I am experimenting with NoSQL.

As per the docs [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1307nosqlforjson3/) there exists a class called [DB](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/javadoc/com/ibm/nosql/json/api/DB.html?lang=en) with which one can interact with the database.

```
javax.sql.DataSource ds =(javax.sql.DataSource)InitialContext.lookup("jdbc/DB2");
com.ibm.json.nosql.DB db = NoSQLClient.getDB (ds);
```

I have the com.ibm.json package but I do not have the com.ibm.json.nosql package, and I cannot find it anywhere. Which jar file do I need to download/in which jar file is it located in (if I already have it -- but I imported every single one in /path/to/db2/sqllib/java with no luck.

[EDIT] I also imported all jar files in C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\json\lib

Sorry for deleting, I had missed that and thought I found my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are few errors in the article you're looking at. The class name is `com/ibm/nosql/json/api/DB` and the JAR file name is `nosqljson.jar`, not `db2nosql.jar`. There were changes in DB2 10.5 fix pack 3 that don't seem to be fully reflected in the article. You may want to contact one of its authors via developerWorks, see if they have an update.